# What is the best method to trim the path off a captured glob?

Tags: php, glob

I use the glob to capture my images here:

```
$images = glob("img/lot/".$_SESSION["lotNumb"].$ds."*.jpg")
```

When I echo this out, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => img/lot/01/1.jpg
    [1] => img/lot/01/2.jpg
    [2] => img/lot/01/3.jpg
    [3] => img/lot/01/4.jpg
)
```

I have tried using ltrim to reduce it down to just the file name, but this is what I get in my foreach loop. What is the best way to do this?

this:

```
foreach($images as $image) 
        {
            $image = ltrim($image, "img/lot/".$lot);
            echo $image;
        }
```

Gives me this:

> .jpg
>
> 2.jpg
>
> 3.jpg
>
> 4.jpg

I lose the "1" off the first iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) combined with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this:

```
$images = array_map("basename", $images);
```

Comment: Nice clean answer, I always forget about `array_map`!

Comment: This give me an error array to string conversion

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\buildHtml.php on line 74

73:$image = array_map("basename", $images);
74:echo $image."<br>";

Comment: @ThurmanJenner Please post a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) link how you use my code

Comment: @ThurmanJenner You have an array so just use: `print_r($images);` or to loop through each value do: `foreach($images as $image) echo $image . "<br>";`

Comment: I think I got it. I put that code inside the loop instead of before it. It works now.

Comment: @ThurmanJenner You're welcome! (FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893999/what-is-the-best-method-to-trim-the-path-off-a-captured-glob/29894085?noredirect=1#comment47911527_29893999)